# Crystal Report Load Report Failed in VS2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I trying to create an application in c# with Crystal Report and then I create setup file using publish wizard and delivery to my client.

Now I use following code to bind crystal report in c#.

```
          ReportDocument doc = new ReportDocument();
          doc.Load("D//CrystalReport1.rpt",CrystalDecisions.Shared.OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy);
    
            doc.SetDataSource(dt);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = doc;
            crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

At client Side generate following error.

> ```
> fmPrint 
> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click 
> Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If 
> you click Quit, the application will close immediately.
>
> Load report failed
>
> CrystalDecisions.shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed → System Run...
>     at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.Open(...
>     at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.Open(Object...
>     at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocum...
>     — End of inner exception stack trace —
>     at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocum...
> ```
>
> [image: Error generate snapshots]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Load report failed.' exception occurs when the path specified for the .rpt file is incorrect. Please check the file path again. Also try the below code.

**When working for web**

```
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("\\CrystalReport1.rpt")",CrystalDecisions.Shared.OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy)
```

Prefer to put the .rpt file in a folder and also specify the folder location.For eg.

Make a Folder Reports inside solution and consolidate all the .rpt files inside the folder

```
doc.Load(Server.MapPath("\\Reports\\CrystalReport1.rpt")",CrystalDecisions.Shared.OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy)
```

**When working for window**

```
doc.Load(@"D//CrystalReport1.rpt",CrystalDecisions.Shared.OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByTempCopy)
```

trying using with a sign '@'. Hope it helps!

Comment: yeah , Is it necessary to put crystal1.rpt file in "D" drive on client computer?

Comment: no! because the above user posted its question with d drive mentioned in it hence d drive is written.